# Content not showing past iframe

Tags: html, css, web, youtube-iframe-api

i have a website and i want to embed a Youtube player as a background (full width and height) and i want to add a white bar with icons to act as buttons to activate the slider above the youtube player.

Here is a picture that may help me explain it.
[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUEaq.png)

But when i add code past my iframe tag it wont show up on my website and it doesn´t even show up at the source code at chrome.

HTML:

```html
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe class="ytplayer" width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/z9Ul9ccDOqE?loop=1&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&controls=0&playlist=z9Ul9ccDOqE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen</iframe>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.video-container, #content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -10;
}
.video-container {
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 0;
height: 0;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -10;
}
.ytplayer {
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Might have to do with missing the closing `>` on your `<ifame>` tag. Most times, validating your code pays off.

Comment: That did the trick thanks! That took me so long to realise..

Comment: You should use an IDE. Most have code validation and code completion tools. Makes developing a lot faster. You're welcome (to [so]). However, you should probably delete this question. Usually questions around `typo`s are not useful to others so they get closed. For me it's mind-blowing that people upvoted yours. Up-votes are usually awarded on research effort and being useful for others. Your question is decently formulated, but doesn't excel in any of the two... It will, most probably, be closed.